# Can Linux ldap users still available if ldap server is unlinked?

Tags: authentication, pam, ldap

I have a Linux with some users have their password in  `/etc/shadow` and other authenticate through LDAP.

Is there a way to make user that have their password stored on ldap continuing to be available (They can continue to authenticate in Linux) if ldap link is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You want [sssd](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/).
As long as the user has logged in once, they will be able to log in again if the LDAP server is unavailable.

For a detailed howto guide, see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/SSSD-Introduction.html#about-sssd
*(The guide is meant for RedHat, but is similar to other distros)*